# Make a combobox fire changed event when first (already selected default) element is clicked in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm designing a webpage where I have a combobox (drop down list) and it has several items in it. I want to be able to click the element and select the first item and it should fire the changed event.

Initial situation:

[image]

I will click the button next to 1/2000 and:

[image]

Afterwards, if I click on 1/2000, I want the changed event to fire. I know it is simple with jQuery, but I couldn't find how to search for this problem so couldn't find an answer.

Thanks, Can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is fired when you select the option, if you want to do something when it's fgired you should do:

```
$('#yourselect').change(function(){
   alert('changed');
});
```

Look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5wc37/

EDIT - tanks to james now i understand what the poster want. One thing you coukd do is binding the click event to the select and check if the target is an option or a select. if it's an option, do what you want:

```
$('select#yourselect').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName === "OPTION"){
        alert(this.value);
    };
});
```

fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5wc37/12/

Comment: I think the problem the OP is having is that the change event does not fire if the already selected option is clicked again.

Comment: This is what I already have. However, try and see if you click the currently selected option, nothing happens, I need something to happen.

Comment: Ok now i understand. I edited my answer, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/5wc37/12/

Answer (score 1):

I think James is right, the question is not how to simply detect a change, he rather wants to know detect the click.

You could use this code but you need to find a way to make it not fire twice if another option is selected:

```
$('select option').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('select').trigger('change');
});
$('select').change(function(){
    alert("Bam!");
});
```